# mxnet-mkl Floating point exception (core dumped) in CPU Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-26xx v4

Tags: intel-mkl, mxnet

i used command "pip install mxnet-mkl" ,when i import mxnet get Floating point exception (core dumped)

```
        import mxnet
        Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

more detail https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/12105

anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to build MXNet from source with Intel MKL-DNN Backend

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet
cd incubator-mxnet
git checkout 1.2.0
git submodule update --init --recursive
make -j USE_OPENCV=1 USE_MKLDNN=1 USE_BLAS=mkl
```